# Integrating new plugins into project(something with manifest)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am having some problems integrating Chartboost ads into my project. I am using Official Chartboost plugin available on their site. After I add(to cardboard manifest) "ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" game starts, but I can't click on the ads.

If I try to add permissions and activity from Cardboard manifest to Chartboost manifest... game crashes.

Chartboost Manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Cardboard manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.plugins.unity.UnityCardboardActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

is there any "secret" way that I should know to have those 2 plugins working together?

Comment: As a side note - Unity ads are good and very easy to implement in Unity games (duh).